# SQL Developer Select Max Record and Entire Row For Each ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new to using SQL and I haven't been able to find any previous posts that seem to answer my question.  I need a statement that will give me the latest approved submission for every customer in the database and all rows/columns of data associated with that submission.  Each submission is assigned a unique id number and is in a column called ASMT_ID.  The unique customer id number is a column called PRTPT_ID.

So, for each PRTPT_ID in the database T_FINANCIAL_ITEM, I want to find the MAX ASMT_ID for each customer and display all columns and rows of data associated with each PRTPT_ID, but only if the STTS_NAME is equal to "Approved".

In my simple terms what I'm trying to do:

```
select * from T_FINANCIAL_ITEM
For each PRTPT_ID SELECT MAX ASMT_ID
WHERE STTS_NAME = 'Approved'
GROUP by PRTPT_ID
```

****UPDATE****
Rather than using the asmt_id, I will need to analyze two other fields in the same table FYE_DT and SUBM_TYPE.

The criteria is:

1. The most recent FYE_DT with a stts_name 'Approved' (i.e. 2011 before 2010).
2. In the most recent fye_dt, the audited subm_type
3. In the most recent fye_dt, if their is no audited subm_type, the unaudited subm_type
4. It will pull all rows of data associated with the submission meeting the criteria

For example:

```
PRTPT_ID    ASMT_ID FYE_DT                       SUBM_TYPE_NAME  
8493000000  18016   30-JUN-09 12.00.00.000000000 AM Unaudited/A-133  
8493000000  19574   30-JUN-09 12.00.00.000000000 AM Audited/A-133  
8493000000  28039   30-JUN-10 12.00.00.000000000 AM Unaudited/A-133  
8493000000  33620   30-JUN-10 12.00.00.000000000 AM Audited/A-133  
9481000000  38049   31-DEC-10 12.00.00.000000000 AM Unaudited/Non-A133  
9481000000  58020   31-DEC-09 12.00.00.000000000 AM Audited/Non-A-133  
9481000000  48139   31-DEC-11 12.00.00.000000000 AM Unaudited/Non-A-133
```

Result:

```
PRTPT_ID    ASMT_ID FYE_DT                       SUBM_TYPE_NAME  
8493000000  33620   30-JUN-10 12.00.00.000000000 AM Audited/A-133  
9481000000  48139   31-DEC-11 12.00.00.000000000 AM Unaudited/Non-A-133
```

Note: There can be multiple rows of data associated with these results.  I need to have all of the rows of data.

Comment: What database are you using?  Does "SQL Developer" in your title imply that you are using an Oracle database and the Oracle SQL Developer front-end?

Comment: Which flavour of SQL? MSSQL/MYSQL/Oracle etc.?

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, I am using Oracle SQL Developer front-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One relatively standard approach would be to use analytic functions.  If I understand your update, it sounds like you want the `ORDER BY` clause to be something like

```
select *
  from (select t.*,
               rank() over (partition by prtpt_id
                                      order by fye_dt desc,
                                               (case when subm_type_name like 'Audited%'
                                                     then 2
                                                     when subm_type_name like 'Unaudited%'
                                                     then 1
                                                     else 0
                                                  end) desc) rnk
          from t_financial_item t
         where stts_name = 'Approved')
 where rnk = 1
```

Comment: Your first approach seems to work, but it only pulls in one row of data for the max record.  I need all the rows of data associated with the max record.

Comment: @Craig_C - I updated my answer to use the `rank` function rather than `row_number`.  That will return multiple rows if there can be multiple rows with the same `asmt_id`.  It sounded to me, though, like this was a unique value from your description so I'm not sure how there can be duplicate rows.  If my edit doesn't help you, it would be helpful to post some sample data and the expected output so that we can better assist you.

Comment: The asmt_id represents a unique submission, but there are several programs reported under each submission. Each program is reported on a different line, which is why I need all the rows.  <br/>     <br/> Your revised statement works perfectly.  However, I found a new twist.  <br/>

Comment: The max asmt_id does not always give me the latest record. So, what I now need to analyze is a combination of the YEAR and the SUBMISSION_TYPE fields in the same table. I need the most recent YEAR and the audited submission_type first, if there is no audited submission in the most recent year, then look at the unaudited submission. To make matters worse, there are more than one type of audited and unaudited submission type. For example Unaudited/No-Audit and Unaudited/A-133. I can provide more detail if necessary!

Comment: @Craig_C - Some sample data and the expected output would definitely be helpful.  Please edit your question to post that information, though, rather than putting it in a comment.

Comment: @Craig_C - Updated with the new ordering criteria.

Answer (score 0):

What's your table structure? This would appear to be what you're looking for:

```
select MAX(ASMT_ID),PRTPT_ID from PRTPT_ID_TABLE p
   INNER JOIN ASMT_ID_TABLE a on p.PRTPT_ID = a.PRTPT_ID
   WHERE STTS_NAME = 'Approved' 
   GROUP by PRTPT_ID
```

but I don't see any tables. Is T_FINANCIAL_ITEM the table or the database name?

Comment: T_FINANCIAL_ITEM is the table name

Comment: I entered the following statement: select MAX(ASMT_ID),PRTPT_ID from T_FINANCIAL_ITEM
WHERE STTS_NAME = 'Approved'
GROUP by PRTPT_ID ; It looks like it found the max record, but it didn't pull in all the rows/columns of data for each PRTPT_ID

Comment: You need to join the table against itself then